# Download a file from a Variable URL c#

Tags: c#, variables, url, download

We have been requested to go and Download an order file from our customers site via a url.
I want to do something like this.

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;

// Create a new WebClient instance.
using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
{
    myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
    // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);        
}
```

But the URL will be variable as we have to specify the Date and Time within the URL we post.

And the File we download will be variable also.

As I'm new to C# I would like some advise as to how to achieve this?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You say the URL/File will be variable, based on what? Do you have an example of a possible URL? I do not see where the problem is? You are not sure how to construct a URL based on Date and Time?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the URLs will be generated. Do they follow a pattern? Do you know them in advance?

```
private void GetVariableFile(string remoteUri, string filename) {
string myStringWebResource = null;

// Create a new WebClient instance.
using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient()) {
    myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
    // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
    //Do stuffs        
    }
}
```

You might wanna pass the Uri & the file obtained to a method which will handle the download and the elaboration, or in case you need to return the result, change the return type so that it can return the info you need.